# PHP code to syntax-format XML content in a `pre` tag

Tags: php, html, syntax-highlighting, pre

I'm looking for way to format the XML syntax displayed in a `pre` tag on my sandbox web.

If you know how, please show me.

Comment: "format" how? Please elaborate?

Comment: Can you give an example of the XML, the PHP and the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at **[Hyperlight](http://code.google.com/p/hyperlight/)** or **[GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)**  (in PHP).

Perhaps you'd prefer to use a Javascript script: consider **[this list](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/)**.

Comment: I find the SyntaxHighlighter to be to one! Thank you grphox

Answer (score 3):

If you want syntax highlighting then this is the only script / plugin you need -> http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

This is javascript though and will format it within the browser

Comment: I find the SyntaxHighlighter to be to one! Thank you ManseUK