# PHP code to align XML content in a `pre` tag

Tags: php, html, alignment, pre

I want to align the XML syntax displayed in a pre tag on a web page.

As showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008578/php-code-to-syntax-format-xml-content-in-a-pre-tag/8008826#8008826), we have plenty of solution to highlight the syntax but not align them i.e. adding a number of preceeding spacings for the `code block`.

If you know how, please show me.

The original XML text:

```
<abb><ccc></ccc><ccc><edd></edd></ccc></abb>
```

After aligned, it should be:

```
<abb>
    <ccc>
    </ccc>
    <ccc>
        <edd>
        </edd>
    </ccc>
</abb>
```

Comment: Same as last time you asked this question - you need to add more details ... add the XML as it is now and what format you want it presented in -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008578/php-code-to-syntax-format-xml-content-in-a-pre-tag

Comment: @ManseUK Last time the question is about `syntax highlight`. This one is about `alignment`.

Comment: My point was more about the comments you received before - give some example code, some example XML, and at least what you want the end result to be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) class to format the XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML($youtXMLString); 
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXml();
```